# Jupyter Notebook: duplicated scatter plot using when using ipywidgets

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm trying to control the display of a scatter plot with a checkbox. When I built it using the interact function it worked as expected. The plot was shown or hidden based on the value in the checkbox.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import interact, widgets
%matplotlib inline

def on_change(Display):
    if Display == True:
        plt.scatter(x,y)
        plt.show()  
    return Display

interact(on_change, Display=False);
```

When I tried to do the same thing using the observe function every time I clicked on the checkbox I get an additional plot displayed below. What do I need to do to get it to redraw the same plot so it works like the example above?

I suppose something in the interact example is clearing the display but it's not clear how to do this manually.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import interact, widgets
%matplotlib inline

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
y = [5,2,4,2,1,4,5,2]

def on_change(change):
    if change['new'] == True:
        scat = plt.scatter(x,y)
        plt.show()   

cb = widgets.Checkbox(False, description = "Display")
cb.observe(on_change, names='value')
display(cb)
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of alterations I made to your example to hopefully demonstrate what you want. I have taken a more object-oriented route, not sure if you specifically wanted to avoid it but it helps achieve your desired outcome, it seems like you are moving towards a simple GUI here.

1) Include an Output widget (`out`) - basically a cell output which you can display like a normal widget. You can use a context manager block (`with out:`) when you want to print to that specific output widget. You can also clear the widget with `out.clear_output()`

2) Use the object oriented interface in matplotlib rather than using plt. I find this easier to control which plots are displayed and in which location at the right times.

- temporarily suspend the interactive matplotlib with plt.ioff()
- Create your figure and axis with `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`. NB figures can have multiple axes/subplots but we only need one.
- 'plot' the scatter data to your axis using `ax.scatter(x,y)`, but this won't cause it to appear.
- Explicitly display the figure with `display(fig)`.

I'm assuming you want your figure to be replotted each time you check the box, so I have included it in the observe function. If your figure doesn't change, it would make sense to move it outside of the loop.

---

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import interact, widgets
%matplotlib inline

out = widgets.Output()

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
y = [5,2,4,2,1,4,5,2]

def on_change(change):
    if change['new'] == True:
        with out:
            plt.ioff()
            fig,ax = plt.subplots()
            ax.scatter(x,y)
            display(fig)
    else:
        out.clear_output()

cb = widgets.Checkbox(False, description = "Display")
cb.observe(on_change, names='value')
display(cb)
display(out)
```